# How to access WindowManager using application context?

Tags: android, android-context, android-windowmanager

I have a scenario where in I have to use WindowManager with application context, I don't Activity context there.

But if I try to get WindowManager with application class, sometimes I get below exception.
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Tried to access visual service WindowManager from a non-visual

```
2021-09-01 14:23:07.877 12079-12201/com.example.sample E/ContextImpl: Tried to access visual service WindowManager from a non-visual Context:com.example.sample.MyApplication@8a55111 WindowManager should be accessed from Activity or other visual Context. Use an Activity or a Context created with Context#createWindowContext(int, Bundle), which are adjusted to the configuration and visual bounds of an area on screen.
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Tried to access visual service WindowManager from a non-visual Context:com.example.sample.MyApplication@8a55111
    at android.app.ContextImpl.getSystemService(ContextImpl.java:2076)
    at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSystemService(ContextWrapper.java:859)
    ...
```

Is there any way where I can access to WindowManger using application context ?

```
public static Point getScreenSize(Context context) {
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getRealSize(size);
    return size;
}
```

Comment: Since `getRealSize()` is deprecated and will not work reliably in all environments (e.g., Android 12L+ tablets, foldables, Chrome OS), you appear to have far bigger problems than your choice of `Context`.

Comment: @CommonsWare, then what's the way out for me if I want to get the screen size using application context.

Comment: Getting the screen size is an anti-pattern. Again, that will not work reliably in all environments.