# How to get screen resolution of a device in non activity class?

Tags: android, android-view

Was using the below code, the context here is application context.

```
public static Point getScreenSize(Context context) {
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    return WindowMangerKt.currentWindowMetricsPointCompat(wm);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getRealSize(size);
    return size;
}
```

Two problems with this.

1. display.getRealSize() is deprecated.
2. And using WindowManager in non visual context throws below error.
   java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Tried to access visual service WindowManager from a non-visual Context:com.sample.MyApplication@1c3510e

And the one where without using context, we get Resources and get displayMetrics, this doesn't give the actual resolution, it doesn't add the system bar/navigation bar height. (It is not adding up the navigation bar height)

```
object ScreenUtils {
    fun getScreenWidth() = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.widthPixels
    fun getScreenHeight() = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.heightPixels
}
```

The above code give resolution of device as 1080x2177 where as actual resolution of the physical device is 1080x2400

I want to know the actual device resolution in non activity class.

Comment: As I noted in [your previous, near-duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73568808/115145), getting the device screen resolution is an anti-pattern. It will not work as you expect in many environments (phones in split-screen mode, Android 12L+ tablets, foldables, Chrome OS).

Comment: @CommonsWare, Right, just added more context and actual use case to the qn. My req doesn't fall into (phones in split-screen mode, Android 12L+ tablets, foldables, Chrome OS), just the normal ones.